# How to insert "C:\" in text column, PL/pgSQL

Tags: plpgsql, redshift

I'm currently facing a strange issue on my PL/pgSQL query to insert string in text column, i will explain:

I have a table with following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Loading_Info
            (
                ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY ,
                Vendor_Loc VARCHAR(500),
                Dest_Loc VARCHAR(500)
);
```

This table will contain file's location for data loading.

My insert query is as follow :

```
INSERT INTO Loading_Info
    (
      ID,
      Vendor_Loc,
      Dest_Loc
    )
    VALUES
    (
      '1',
      's3://ind-uat-ics/uat/telco/',
      'C:\ind-uat-ics\uat\telco\'
    );

    COMMIT;
```

When I am trying to execute this query on SQL workbench I got following error :

```
[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: unterminated quoted string at or near "'C:\ind-uat-ics\uat\telco\',
        )"
```

Have you got any idea how to insert these characters to be considered as string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to *escape* the backslashes of your string because `\` is the *escape* character itself and therefore special.

I believe the following fixes your problem:

```
INSERT INTO Loading_Info
(
  ID,
  Vendor_Loc,
  Dest_Loc
)
VALUES
(
  '1',
  's3://ind-uat-ics/uat/telco/',
  'C:\\ind-uat-ics\\uat\\telco\\'
);

COMMIT;
```

Also per ypercube:

> Or change a setting to on. See [String Constants](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html) (the section under Caution) and [standard_conforming_strings](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-STANDARD-CONFORMING-STRINGS)

The aforementioned docs discuss different solutions in addition to also mentioning:

> Any other character following a backslash is taken literally. Thus, to include a backslash character, write two backslashes (\).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @user3040157 No problem! Best of luck!